# Reading a csv file in python

Tags: python, windows, file, csv

I want to open and read file Mappe1.csv but it is not working. I am using Python 3.6.5 Anaconda. I do not know what I am doing wrong. Any ideas?

File Mappe1.csv contains:

```
A;B;C
1;4;7
2;5;8
3;6;9
```

The python code for opening Mappe1.csv looks like the following:

```
import csv


class CSVAdapter:
    def read_csv(self):
        with open("C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/General/DesignUploader/Mappe1.csv") as file:
            dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(file.read(1024))
            csv_file = csv.reader(file.readlines(), dialect, quotechar='"')
            print("A")
            csv_file_list = []
            for row in file:
                print("B")
            for row in csv_file:
                print("C")
                csv_file_list.append(row)
        return csv_file_list
```

The printout is "A" only. "B" and "C" does not get printed which leads me to the conclusion that the file was not read correctly.

Are there any python/windows settings required to allow Python to read a file?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: That call to `read(1024)` reads the whole file, leaving nothing left to read. Then you call `readlines()`, which also reads the whole file, or would if there were anything left. Then `for row in file:` also reads the whole file. And, of course, so does `for row in csv_file:`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to supply to `csv.reader` file object, not `file.readlines()`. If you want to print Bs, you need to seek to the beginning of file, similar with the Cs.

```
import csv

def read_csv():
    with open("data.csv") as file:
        dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(file.read(1024))
        csv_file = csv.reader(file, dialect, quotechar='"')

        print("A")
        csv_file_list = []

        file.seek(0)

        for row in file:
            print("B")

        file.seek(0)

        for row in csv_file:
            print("C")
            csv_file_list.append(row)
    return csv_file_list

print(read_csv())
```

Prints:

```
A
B
B
B
B
C
C
C
C
[['A', 'B', 'C'], ['1', '4', '7'], ['2', '5', '8'], ['3', '6', '9']]
```

Answer (score 0):

csv.reader takes a file object as first parameter, not a list which is what file.readlines() returns.

So your line:

```
csv_file = csv.reader(file.readlines(), dialect, quotechar='"')
```

should be:

```
csv_file = csv.reader(file, dialect, quotechar='"')
```

your for loop to print('B') should be:

```
for row in file.readlines():
    print('B')
```

your for loop to print('C') should work fine like it is although it is worth noting that you could directly set csv_file_list = list(csv_file). And you should reset your file to the first line with:

```
file.seek(0)
```

Answer (score -1):

In your code, you are only printing `A`, `B`, or `C`. Try printing the whole line instead. You will see that the `row` in `cvs_file` is an object where we are only accessing one part of it. From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html), see the example:

```
 >>> import csv
 >>> with open('eggs.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
 ...     spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
 ...     for row in spamreader:
 ...         print(', '.join(row))
 Spam, Spam, Spam, Spam, Spam, Baked Beans
 Spam, Lovely Spam, Wonderful Spam
```

From this example, try:

```
 for row in csv_file:
     print(','.join(row))
```

instead.

Finally, you will want to change the way the files are being read. Your `cvs_files` is using `delimiter` of `;`. Try that instead of the `dialect`. And your `file` does not actually have any property `row`. You will need to

```
lines = file.readlines()
```

Answer (score -1):

This is alternative solution. I use [the Pandas tool](https://pandas.pydata.org/) for reading CSV file when working with data. The code is actually very simple, and outputs the answer into a Pandas `DataFrame` data structure. For me, tt is cleaner to read extracted information and easier to process than the csv tool.

Here is snippet:

```
import pandas

df = pandas.read_csv('C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/General/DesignUploader/Mappe1.csv')
print (df)
```